# Measure based Probability arising in a simple question

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a unit circle. Obviously, the circle contains all sorts of chords ranging in length from 0 to 2. Suppose a line chord  is chosen at random (which of course can be done in more than one way, that however, would not affect our problem). It seems intuitively obvious that the probability of a random chord  turning up to be exactly of length, say, 1 is zero.

Here both the sample space and favourable space are geometric in nature but none of the two corresponds to simple length or some area. My question is how we can theoretically make it rigorous and arrive at the probability zero. I would be highly obliged for any explanations/insights/references.

Comment: $\mu (E)=m\{x\in [0,2\pi]: e^{ix} \in E\}$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: there uncountable many probability measures in the set of chords, moreover, you need to define a $\sigma $-algebra in this set of chords before to define a probability measure in this space. Moreover: there are infinitely many different probability measures where the probability of any chosen chord is zero

Comment: So I was asking for one $\sigma$ algebra and one probability measure giving the probability of a chord of a given length  as zero

Answer (score 1):

Choosing a random chord amounts to choosing a pair of angles $(\alpha,\beta)$ from the set $[0,2\pi)^2$. The set of $(\alpha,\beta)$ pairs that correspond to a chord of length 1 is a one-dimensional subset of this two-dimensional square region, so it has Lebesgue measure 0 and therefore (if your probability measure is continuous) probability 0.